# Undefined variable with laravel and blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I know it's probably super simple, but I just started using laravel today, I've always been on codeigniter before. The problem I have is that laravel tells me that my variable is not defined ...

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $data['pageTitle']='Connexion';

    return view('login')->with($data);
}
```

The line concerned in login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.header', $pageTitle)
```

Error:

```
"Undefined variable: pageTitle (View: G:\Winginx\home\laravel\public_html\resources\views\login.blade.php)"
```

Thanks !

Comment: why are you passing a second argument to the `extends` directive? btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to use `$pageTitle` variable but you do not pass it to the view.

So, to fix this you can change this line in the view:

```
@extends('layout.header', $data['pageTitle'])
```

Or you can change method in controller to:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('login', ['pageTitle' => 'Connexion']);
}
```

Comment: Not working, the first method now give this error: Undefined variable: data and second do same thing :/

Comment: @KarylLamoureux I'm pretty sure you can't get this error message. You're doing something wrong, because the code above is 100% working.